# ¿En que ruta puedo encontrar el archivo de mi BBDD SQLite?

Tags: java, android

creé una base de datos para almacenar respuestas de una encuesta, pero no puedo ver mi base de datos, no veo el package de mi aplicacion y ni siquiera puedo acceder al directorio data/data/mi.example.myapplication/databases No puedo!!
Porfavor necesito ayuda.

**EDITADO:**

Aqui cree mi base de datos y la volvi accesible desde la tarjeta de memoria.

```
encuestadoSQLiteHelper encuestado = new encuestadoSQLiteHelper(this, "DBEncuestado", null, 1);
    final SQLiteDatabase db = encuestado.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "/data/carpetahola/com.example.pablo.myapplication/databases/DBEncuestad‌​o";
            String backupDBPath = "backdatabase.sqlite";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Surgió un error:"+e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente no podrás ver tu base de datos debido a que el dispositivo en el cual estas depurando la aplicación no esta rootiado(súper usuario) , debido a esto el directorio **data** estará vacio o no te dejara acceder, espero poder ayudarte, saludos

Comment: Hola, si entiendo. Lo que pasa es que esta aplicacion es para que mas usuarios la usen, por decirlo asi para darla a otra persona y que la instale en su dispositivo. Pero entonces yo no le puedo decir a la persona que rootee su dispositivo porque o si no, no la puede usar, me entiendes? Entonces que puedo hacer?

Comment: Y puedo rootear mi dispositivo con z4root? es un S3 mini.

Answer (score 0):

La base de datos es accesible en varios casos.

1- Si el dispositivo esta rooteado.
2- Si el dispositivo no es físico. Es un emulador.
3- Si la base de datos se guarda en la `tarjeta SD`

En este último caso hay que tener en cuenta que no todos los teléfonos disponen de tarjeta SD.

Para guardar la `base de datos` en la `tarjeta SD` se debe de cambiar el valor de `currentPath` a `/sdcard/`